# Very irregular C problem, passing array of arrays and then printing to console

Tags: c

This is my first time with a compiled language, I'm not sure what else to google because there isn't anything obvious.  There is a fair amount of source code, so I put it all here:  https://pastebin.com/G0tr20mJ

In effect it boils down to:

```
#define NROWS = 10
#define NCOLS = 10
 
// There is more complex logic in this function that has been removed
// Suffice to say, there is an iterative process going through row x
// column(s) by row x column(s)
// Printing the values to the console shows that all the correct 
// locations are being assigned
// Execution to this point is exactly as expected
void funcOfFoos(short arrayOfArrays [][NCOLS], int *rowPtr, int *colPtr)
{ 
    printf("Marking (%d, %d)\n", *rowPtr, *colPtr);
    arrayOfArrays[*rowPtr][*colPtr] = 1;
}
 
// Goal here is to print the contents of the 2d array in the form
// 10
// 9
// 8
// 7
// 6
// 5
// 4
// 3
// 2
// 1
//    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
// Only random values are missing at this point
// I don't understand why it fails
void dispArray(const short arrayToPrint[][NCOLS])
{
    for (size_t r=0; r<NROWS; r++)
    {
        printf("Row %2zu", (NROWS - r));
        for (size_t c=0; c<NCOLS; c++)
        {
            // Should be
            // if (arrayToPrint[(NROWS - r - 1)][c] == 1)
            if (arrayToPrint[(NROWS - r)][c] == 1)

            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

It's printing the phrase BOB.

The instructions to write the B's are identical, yet the results for each character are different.  I've never seen a program fail that way, if I made a mistake my expectation would be for it to be the same on both.

Around 10% of all three characters is missing, and I'm not sure why row[21] has random values, it's clearly out of range and I don't understand why.

**EDIT: row[21] is random because it's out of range, thanks OutrageousBacon**

Complete expected and actual results are in the pastebin.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you reasonably certain your turtle `commands[]` are correct?

Comment: Yes, 100%.   "Marking (X, Y)" has completely correct output.

Comment: Well, for one thing dispArray outer loop starts with r of 0, so first pass through will access arrayToPrint[10][0], which is out of bounds assuming arrayToPrint is 10x10.

Comment: You pass `int * rowPtr, int * colPtr` to `moveTurtle()`... why are these integers pointers?  (probably not the problem, but still odd)

Comment: @m0dem - Because this is the prof's way to teach us pointers

Comment: @OutrageousBacon - Good point, that is one of the issues; causing the output on row 21.  But the lesser one.

Comment: `dispArray(const short arrayToPrint[][ -> NCOLS <- ])` did you write this or your professor?

Comment: @m0dem - The professor

Comment: [NROWS - r] ; typically your array has indices 0..NROWS-1; however you are looping from 0 .. NROWS-1 and subtracting, so you are referencing one row beyond the last.   Also `#define NROWS = 10` is not valid in C; so this bit isn't from your program that compiled.   Third, the advice to condense your problem into the shortest reproducible example isn't just for the convenience of the readers, most people find their mistakes themselves by going through the exercise.   Dropping a link to a bunch of code helps nobody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else
{
    // printf("Skipping (%d, %d)\n", *rowPtr, *colPtr);
    if (floor[*rowPrt][*colPtr] == 1)
        printf("WARNING: we are about to erase (%d, %d)\n", *rowPtr, *colPtr);
    floor[*rowPtr][*colPtr] = 0;
}
```

Try this... it should work if `Marking (X, Y)` truly is printing out correctly.

```
void dispArray(short *arrayToPrint)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < NROWS; ++r)
    {
        printf("Row %d", r);
        for (int c = 0; c < NCOLS; ++c)
        {
            if (arrayToPrint[r][c] == 1)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: No joy.  I double checked the Marking (X, Y) again too: https://imgur.com/a/6aIVeNO
Also I was inverting the rows, to count down from NROWS because (0,0) shall be in the lower left.

Comment: Though in this case I don't suppose the row order matters, same result either way.

Comment: If Marking(X, Y) is correct (arrayToPrint[Y][X] == 1) this will work.  Also your row is going to be Y axis and column is X axis, so it would be Marking (Y, X)

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be that your `funcOfFoos` (which appears nowhere in the complete source code) is being called in a draw function, which is absolutely worthless and tells you nothing about what ends up in the final `arrayToPrint`

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS inverting them.  funcOfFoos is lines 199 and 200, I just tried to clip it out because I hate posts with a wall of code.

Comment: I added a bit of code above that will tell you if you are overwriting your ones with zeros.

Comment: Already tried, also tried just printing raw 1's and 0's.

Comment: And there were zero cases in which a 1 was replaced with a 0?

Comment: Oh christ I was in the wrong spot, there is a problem there.  THANK YOU